# How to save a text file (CSV) with UTF-8 without BOM encoding in VBA (Excel)?

Tags: vba, excel, utf-8, adodb

So this was my initial question. ***The answer*** to my question below, seems to be that the only solution to get UTF-8 (and UTF-8 without BOM) encoding, is to use the ADODB.Stream object.
 The answer to my new question in the subject line is posted as a code.

*I am sitting here and trying to `Save` an Excel sheet as a `.CSV`-file with a VBA macro.
 
However, I am wondering if it matters whether I use `ADODB`/`ADODB.Stream` or just `.SaveAs` `Fileformat:=xlCSV`. I have tried to Google it, and it seems like I cannot find an answer to which method is the "best". I would need it to be comma delimited, UTF-8, and double quotations ("") as text-identifier.



Is it correct that when you use `Fileformat:=`, it is not possible to `SaveAs` UTF-8, since the `xlCSV` is not using that encoding?* **YES, that is correct.**

See my answer for the solution.

Comment: I suggest you.... try it and see! Note that CSV is just a text file so you could even just use text file writing methods.

Comment: Ditto what @Nick.McDermaid said. Give it a try. If you run into problems you cannot resolve, post your code and exactly what's going on & someone will jump in to help you.

Comment: Cheers guys :) I was just wondering about the pros and cons about doing it in these ways.

Comment: @Niclas: Perhaps you will edit your question and split it into a question and a separate answer? This would increase the readability by a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I came in the situation where I needed this code again, and I read the comments and Leonard's answer, which made me update my code together with better descriptions.

This code will convert your Excel sheet and save it as a CSV file with the UTF-8 without BOM encoding. I found this code on a website, so I will not take credit for it. [CSV without BOM link](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvba-corner.livejournal.com%2F5733.html&ei=OOEkVf31O8alsAHUnIHgBA&usg=AFQjCNHm2E0tNI8e3qolNR77dJGsLK3nIQ&sig2=aILAtb4800hyo7qdbuMydQ)

```
Option Explicit

Sub CSVFileAsUTF8WithoutBOM()
Dim SrcRange As Range
Dim CurrRow As Range
Dim CurrCell As Range
Dim CurrTextStr As String
Dim ListSep As String
Dim FName As Variant
Dim UTFStream As Object
Dim BinaryStream As Object

' ADO Constants
Const adTypeBinary = 1 ' The stream contains binary data
Const adTypeText = 2 ' The stream contains text data (default)
Const adWriteLine = 1 ' write text string and a line separator (as defined by the LineSeparator property) to the stream.
Const adModeReadWrite = 3 ' Read/write
Const adLF = 10 ' Line feed only - default is carriage return line feed (adCRLF)
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2 ' Overwrites the file with the data from the currently open Stream object, if the file already exists

' Open this workbook location
ChDrive Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, 1)
ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path

' ask for file name and path
  FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "CSV File (*.csv), *.csv")

' prepare UTF-8 stream
  Set UTFStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")
  UTFStream.Type = adTypeText
  UTFStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
  UTFStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
  UTFStream.LineSeparator = adLF
  UTFStream.Open

  'set field separator
  ListSep = ";"
  'set source range with data for csv file
  If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Set SrcRange = Selection
  Else
    Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  End If

  For Each CurrRow In SrcRange.Rows
    'enclose each value with quotation marks and escape quotation marks in values
    CurrTextStr = ""
    For Each CurrCell In CurrRow.Cells
      CurrTextStr = CurrTextStr & """" & Replace(CurrCell.Value, """", """""") & """" & ListSep
    Next
    'remove ListSep after the last value in line
    While Right(CurrTextStr, 1) = ListSep
      CurrTextStr = Left(CurrTextStr, Len(CurrTextStr) - 1)
    Wend
    'add line to UTFStream
    UTFStream.WriteText CurrTextStr, adWriteLine ' Writes character data to a text Stream object
  Next

  'skip BOM
  UTFStream.Position = 3 ' sets or returns a long value that indicates the current position (in bytes) from the beginning of a Stream object

  'copy UTFStream to BinaryStream
  Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary
  BinaryStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
  BinaryStream.Open ' Opens a Stream object

  'Strips BOM (first 3 bytes)
  UTFStream.CopyTo BinaryStream ' Copies a specified number of characters/bytes from one Stream object into another Stream object

  UTFStream.Flush ' Sends the contents of the Stream buffer to the associated underlying object
  UTFStream.Close ' Closes a Stream object

  'save to file
  BinaryStream.SaveToFile FName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
  BinaryStream.Flush ' Sends the contents of the Stream buffer to the associated underlying object
  BinaryStream.Close ' Closes a Stream object

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

thank you for posting this question and also the solution. It helped me a lot.
Yes, I also found that SaveAs does not save the CSV file in UTF8. In my case it uses shift-JIS. The adodb.stream worked well for me.

However, I am not sure why but I had to declare some constants (enum) you used in the code. (I am really new to VBA so maybe I missed something about why this happens). I added this in the beginning of the function, then it worked perfectly:

```
  Const adTypeText = 2
  Const adModeReadWrite = 3
  Const adTypeBinary = 1
  Const adLF = 10
  Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
  Const adWriteLine = 1
```

I got the value from Microsoft docs.
Once again, thanks!

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question and should be deleted. If you are facing any related issue, then you can ask a new question while mentioning this particular question

Comment: @BalwinderSingh thank you for the feedback. What I wrote should actually be a comment to the question (or to be precise, to the answer, as you may have checked, OP answered his own question by editing it). I managed to use his solution with the modification I wrote above. I thought it can help somebody else too.  Problem is, I do not have enough reputation to comment. If you think it is better for me to copy OP's code and added my modification, kindly let me know.

Comment: My bad. As per the original edit, I thought you were facing some related issue. Now it makes sense after you edited it and it might help others who face similar issue. Cheers